# can't get the screen width and height values in another class

Tags: java, android, screen

I'm making an application, in this application I need the width and height of the display device. Initially I made ​​a calculation of the width and height in one class and then instantly displayed. But to make it look more organized, I separate them in a separate class. This code in the class:

```
public class DisplayMeasurement extends Activity{

public int widthScreen = 0;
public int heightScreen = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void DisplayHeightWidthMeasurement(){
      int Measuredwidth = 0;
      int Measuredheight = 0;
      Point size = new Point();
      WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
              w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

              Measuredwidth = size.x;
              Measuredheight = size.y; 
            }else{
              Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
              Measuredwidth = d.getWidth(); 
              Measuredheight = d.getHeight(); 
            }
        //int sepertiga = Measuredwidth/3;
        //akhir ngukur layar
        set(Measuredwidth,Measuredheight);
    }

    public void set(int Measuredwidth, int Measureheight){
        this.widthScreen = Measuredwidth;
        this.heightScreen = Measureheight;
    }

    public int getWidthScreen(){
     return widthScreen;
    }

    public int getHeightScreen(){
        return heightScreen;
    }   
}
```

then this is a piece of code on mainActivity:

```
  DisplayMeasurement screenValue = new DisplayMeasurement();
    int WidthScreen = screenValue.getWidthScreen();
    int HeightScreen = screenValue.getHeightScreen();


    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    text1.setText("lebar" + WidthScreen);
    text2.setText("tinggi" + HeightScreen);
```

But that I get is the value 0. Is there anyone who has experienced the same thing, or are there who know about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm kind of new to Android but I'll give it a go.

I'm not sure why you're trying to organise code by creating a new Activity which seems to over-complicate things.

```
public class DisplayMeasurement {

    public int widthScreen = 0;
    public int heightScreen = 0;

    public void DisplayMeasurement(Context context){
          Point size = new Point();
          WindowManager w = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.WINDOW_SERVICE);

          if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
               w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);  
               widthScreen = size.x;
               heightScreen = size.y; 
          } else {
               Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
               widthScreen = d.getWidth(); 
               heightScreen = d.getHeight(); 
          }
    }

    public int getWidthScreen(){
        return widthScreen;
    }

    public int getHeightScreen(){
        return heightScreen;
    }   
}
```

And then in your main activity;

```
DisplayMeasurement screenValue = new DisplayMeasurement(this);
int WidthScreen = screenValue.getWidthScreen();
int HeightScreen = screenValue.getHeightScreen();


TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

text1.setText("lebar" + WidthScreen);
text2.setText("tinggi" + HeightScreen);
```

Not sure if it will work though, haven't tested it.

Also, I'm not sure why (have been only coding for 6 months) - but how is DisplayHeightWidthMeasurement() meant to be ever called, when you never call for it. All you do is:

```
DisplayMeasurement screenValue = new DisplayMeasurement();
```

and so your method: DisplayHeightWidthMeasurement, which actually has the logic to get the width and height is never called. You would need to call that first, otherwise it would just return 0, which is what you initialised.

Comment: This seems more or less correct. I might add that you should NEVER instantiate an Activity class manually. Always allow Android to instantiate your Activities. As @user2693394 rightly points out, the reason you are getting 0 values is because you never call your DisplayHeightWidthMeasurement() function to initialize your values.

Comment: Thank you for all. Mistakes which is a shame. "If the method is never called how to change the value in it". Finally I fix the code are offered by @ Jerryl15. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You never call the function `DisplayHeightWidthMeasurement()` so the method in it `set()` is not called yet, so the values of **height** and **width** are zero just as you set, just as @TheIT said it is not a good way to instantiate an `Activity`, you can just define a `Class` that get the **width** and **height** of the diplay rather than use an `Activity`.